# Exponential curve with error term in R

Tags: r, curve-fitting

Can anyone advise how to find sensible start values to fit:

`fExpN <- function(x, a, b, err) {a * exp(b * x + err)}`

Theory-wise this should be just the right model (exp with error component), but I am getting

> singular gradient matrix at initial parameter estimates

no matter what values I am probing.

Comment: I'm confused by the error component. Is that actually a parameter or rather an actual random error (i.e., the residuals that are minimized during fitting). If the former, the model is over-parameterized since `a * exp(b * x + err) = a * exp(b * x) * exp(err) = c * exp(b * x)`.

Comment: And if the latter simply fit the linear model `log(a) + b * x` with `lm`.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion! But, I am not sure there is a way to specify parameters in `lm()` the way you did above. Am I wrong?

Comment: `lm(log(y) ~ x)` does the job.

Comment: This seems to work relatively nicely. But what if error is not really random? Given data I checked it is always greater at the beginning and end of values of x, and almost none in the middle. U-shaped like, but with wide base and quite steep drop and raise. So, is that state dependent? How to add that "wrinkle" into the `lm(log(y) ~ x)`?

Comment: If you have a variance covariate you can model the residual variance structure with the `gls` function from package nlme.

Comment: No, thank you. Improve your question, i.e., make it reproducible and explain clearly what you want to achieve, and I might help you further. But I'm not interested in communication by email. Sorry. If you prefer email you could try a mailing list. If you need help with improving this question or would like to discuss this, you could join the [chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25312/r-public).

Comment: So, then, I suppose that `lm(log(y) ~ x)` should be turned into something like `gls(log(y) ~ x, ...)`. And I think I should specify `weights` parameter, but I am not sure which one of those listed, since the shape is, as I said, U-like. Can you advice, please?